# Why am I getting dart warning 'Depend on referenced packages'?

Tags: dart

I have the following code...

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class MyClass {

}
```

The import statement at the top is giving the error 'Depend on referenced packages'.

I have no clue what this means. My pubspec.yaml is as follows...

```
name: my_app
description: A sample command-line application.
version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  dio: ^4.0.6
  json_serializable: ^6.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

Comment: [depend_on_referenced_packages](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html) says "when importing a package, add a dependency on it to your pubspec". You are using the [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) package, but it is not declared in your `pubspec.yaml`. It is probably available due to being a transitive dependency of [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable).

Answer (score 6):

Add your dependencies on

```
dependencies:
```

not on

```
dev_dependencies:
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line of code under `dependencies` in your `pubspec.yaml` file and run `pub get`.

```
dependencies:
    json_annotation: ^4.5.0
```